# Cannot send e-mail to one account on server

Tags: email, postfix

I am responsible for administering a web and mail server which has a number of users with mailboxes which function correctly. I recently added another user as I wanted to set up a separate e-mail account for a very specifc purpose. I managed to get the account working for sending e-mail to any e-mail address but it will not receive e-mail. The error I get if I try to send an e-mail to it is:

```
Error 550.5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

I don't understand why this is happening for this one account on the server. I have an account setup with the user TSRalert and the e-mail address which works for sending e-mail is TSRalert@tropicalstormrisk.com. There is something else that needs configuring for this account on the server but I don't know what. Can anyone provide assistance please.

The server is running CentOS7 and has postfix and sendmail installed. My mail.cf file contains the following:

```
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.$mydomain
mydomain = tropicalstormrisk.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 550.5.1.1 Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

It means the email account doesn't exist. Check the email routing and also check the logs. Also restart the service for postfix.

Comment: Yes you are right, that is what is in the e-mail logs. Am I correct in thinking that whenever I create a new user account when postfix is running, I have to restart postfix before the e-mail account will work properly? I'll have a go at restarting Postfix tomorrow and see if that solves the problem.